# (-57)8 - (+76)8 using 8’s complement method =?

Tags: octal, digital

I'm doing like (-57)8 + (-76)8 then finding the 8's complement of -76 which i got 2 , and adding that to -57 which in turn gives -55 which is wrong, the answer should be -155. How to get that?

Answer (score 0):

"then finding the 8's complement of -76 which i got 2" implies a 2 digit 8's complement.  `(-57)8 + (-76)8` overflows a 2 digit 8's complement encoding.

Use a wider 8's complement, like 4 digits.

Comment: thnx for the solution but can you explian a little brifely ..

Comment: @user15572601 What part is unclear?  Perhaps make clear how "then finding the 8's complement of -76 which i got 2" is true.

Comment: 'adding 2 to -57 which gives -55 is wrong' , i'm not getting the solution correct!!

Comment: @user15572601 When I asked "What part is unclear?", I was hoping for you to point out what part of this answer was unclear, not a re-iteration of the post.    Please explain how you accomplished "finding the 8's complement of -76 which i got 2".  By you doing so, it will be most effective for me to then show how to get the right answer.  That detail of your line of thinking helps for a crafted answer.

Comment: ,Can you slove the whole for me,as its getting much complicated to know where i'm stuck.

Comment: Without you making clear how you did "finding the 8's complement of -76 which i got 2", I cannot solve the whole for you.  Good luck.

Comment: ty for still helping,"getting the 8's complement was like-  for -76 , 1st i calculated the 7s complement ' 77-76=1' and then added 1 to it for 8s complement '1+1=2'.

Comment: And adding the 8s complement(i.e.2) to -57.

Comment: @SR15572601 Why are you using `77-76=1` instead of `777-76=1` or `7777-76=1` or even a wider 777777?  Why only a 2-digit 77?  The choice of using a 2-digit 77 is important.

Comment: i thought that both the numbers in the question are of 2 digit so i took 77, but if taken 777, then 7s complement will be 777-76=701 & 8s complement would be 701+1=702 and adding it to 1st no '-57+702= 623' in octal,which again is wrong!

Comment: @SR15572601 What is the expected -155 8's complement using 3 digits? (623).